# Superfish menu shows broken structure in IE9, working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, superfish

My superfish menu is working fine in Chrome, Firefox & Safari, but the structure is broken under the IE9. I tried to apply the z-index value and looking for other possible issue for hours now, but I still cannot get it work under the IE9.

Can someone help me o with issue or point me to the right direction. Many thanks!

Here is the demo site:
http://goo.gl/zwNFO

Comment: Wow, that menu fails keyboard accessibility. Not everyone uses a mouse.

Comment: @epascarello thank you, I'm working on that.

Comment: check line 94 of your markup. It appears you have an extra </li>

Comment: @iGanja Yes, thanks so much. I remove the extra </li> and the structure is not broken under IE. However, the sub menus are behind of slider now..

Comment: @jumax I am not sure what version of jQuery you are using, but you have script errors that are trying to reference jQuery .on methods not available until 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of missing closing tags.

```
<div class="site-container full-width" id="section-sub-footer">
<span class="copyright">
```

and maybe this:

```
<div class="site-container full-width" id="section-thirds">
```

Answer (score 0):

with all the floating elements you have, you may be running into z-index ordering issues. you can try this little script i created for IE7 reverse rendering; your mileage may vary.

```
        var zIndexNumber = 10000;
        $('div, span, ul').each(function () {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 1;
        });
```